# How to make browser extension data persist between domains?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, cross-domain, browser-extension, persistent-storage

I'm on my third day of learning browser extensions.

I'm trying to store a variable - just a string - and have access to that variable while accessing different domains. Things I've tried:

1. Cookies (only accessible to one domain)
2. window.localStorage (only accessible to one domain)
3. browser.storage.local (seems to be the best solution, but I can't get it to work)
4. storing the variable in a background-script and calling it from there (can't get it to work)

I'm not really finding any good tutorials on the subject (or at least none that I fully understand). I'm not looking for a complex example here - I want my end code to work something like this:

```
var output = "";
var loginURL = "loginpage.com";
var url = GetURL();

if(url == "loginpage.com"){
    SaveString("Shazaam!");
    output = "String Saved.";
}else{
    output = LoadSavedString();
}

alert(output);

fucntion SaveString(s){
    /* ? */
}

function LoadSavedString(){
    /* ? */
}
```

I want to start out getting an empty alert, go to the "loginpage.com" url to save the sting "Shazaam!" to get an alert "String Saved." and then go to another page and get the alert "Shazaam!" It doesn't seem like it should be that much to ask...

Comment: Why don't you use a database ? You can have free database like Google Firebase : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Comment: @ReaperSoon - Well, my larger problem is that I'm trying to have individual users access a database on each new page load, but they need unique userId's to do it. So I need my extension to store a unique string for each person. So the question is: how do I get my extension to store persistent data on the client-side?